# Await hangs in googleSignIn method on back pressed

Tags: android, dart, google-signin, flutter

I'm trying to implement Google SignIn in a flutter app.
Once I call `signIn()`, the provider correctly show user's Google Account on the smartphone but if the back button is pressed no error is catched and the await hangs indefinitely.
Did someone have the same issue.
Ho to correctly catch the back button.
I'm using following flutter plugins:

```
google_sign_in: ^3.0.0
firebase_auth: ^0.5.0
```

This is the code I currently have.
Second print statement or catch error are never called.

```
print('google signing in');
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn().catchError(() {
                throw new StateError('Google Sign in aborted');
        });
print('google authentification');
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication.catchError(() {
                throw new StateError('Google Sign in aborted');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

ok,

I realize my question was actually a mistake induced by the readme of the google SignIn plugin.
actually, my codes hangs on the second await because googleUser is null.

In the code above, there shoud be a conditional if and exit the method if googleUser is null.

```
print('google signing in');
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn().catchError(() {
                throw new StateError('Google Sign in aborted');
        });
if (googleUser == null) return;
print('google authentification');
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication.catchError(() {
                throw new StateError('Google Sign in aborted');
        });
```